# Why this kind of method of constant variation hold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

1. When we try to find a solution of an ODE like this:
   $$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y+Q(x)=0$$
   We usually ignore $Q(x)$ at first. And find a solution of another equation.
   $$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=0$$
   $$\Rightarrow y=Cexp(-\int P(x)dx)$$
   Then let the constant of this period $C$ be $C(x)$. 
   $$\Rightarrow y=C(x)exp(-\int P(x)dx)$$
   And we get a solution like:
   $$C'(x)exp(-\int P(x)dx)-C(x)exp(-\int P(x)dx)P(x)+Q(x)+P(x)C(x)exp(-\int P(x)dx)=0$$
   $$\Rightarrow C(x)=\int \frac{-Q(x)dx}{exp(-\int P(x)dx)}+C'$$
   $$\Rightarrow y=\int \frac{-Q(x)dx}{exp(-\int P(x)dx)}exp(-\int P(x)dx)+C'exp(-\int P(x)dx)$$
   I don't understand this kind of logic. It seems every time we do like this, we find the right answer by accident.
2. consider a PDE.
   $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}=0$$
   **assuming** that we could ignore $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, we have:
   $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}=0$$
   $$\Rightarrow u=exp(ix)$$
   now consider $x$ as $\theta(x,t)$,where $\theta(x,t)$ is a travelling wave, i.e. $\theta(x,t)$=$kx-wt$, $k$ and $w$ are constants.
   $$u=exp(i(kx-wt))$$
   Then just solve $w(k)$. 
   $$(-wi)exp(i(kx-wt))+(ki)exp(i(kx-wt))+(ki)^3exp(i(kx-wt))$$
   $$\Rightarrow -wi+ki+(ki)^3=0$$
   $$\Rightarrow w=k-k^3$$

This situation is like a stronger one. Not only we consider a constant as a function, but also a travelling wave.

Comment: what is the question ? Notice for 1. that it's not by "accident". We just wish to find a function C(x) s.t. $$C(x)y'(x)+C'(x)y(x)=C(x)Q(x),$$so that the LHS can be written as $(C(x)y(x))'=C(x)Q(x)$. Of course such function $C$ should verify $C'(x)=P(x)C(x)$. Namely, $e^{\int_0^t P(u)du}$ make the job. For 2. we normally use the Fourier transform to get and linear ODE of degree 1. The reason is that the fourier transform we'll (in somehow) kill the $\partial _x$.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the similarity between your method and the constant variation in 1.

Comment: Surb is right for 1 ...you solve the homogeneous equation than vary the parameter.

Comment: Yes, what you get is correct and called variaion of parameter $C$ which is treated as $C(x)$ and obtained finally,